# what is the difference between Coalesce and nullif

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am currently working on an SSRS report that will need to display a Dr's ID based on either their DEA number or NPI number.  I need to be able to do a coalesce on DEA and NPI to find the non-unknown one, which I will then add code to the SSRS report that will display a hover over stating whether the "DEA Number" or "NPI Number" is being displayed.

Would the following SQL accomplish this on the back-end?  From what I have read online it seems like nullif and coalesce are very similar and was wondering what the underlining difference is and if they could be used together to accomplish this requirement.

```
coalesce(nullif(convert(varchar,NationalProviderIdentifier),'0'), DEANumber) as 'Dr Id'
```

Comment: They don't do the same.. `NULLIF` returns null if the two arguments are the same. `COALESCE` returns the first non-null argument. You might be thinking of `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` which are similar https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqltips/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce/

Comment: Did you mean the difference between `coalesce` and `isnull`? Have you read the documentation on [`coalesce`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx), [`isnull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx), and [`nullif`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)?

Comment: Also, [don't convert to varchar without specifying the length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are more or less unrelated.

`coalesce()` takes a *list* of values and returns the first *non-null* value (or `null` if all values are `null`).

`nullif()` takes *two* values and returns the first value, except it returns `null` if the values are equal.

---

If the two were converted to `case` statements, they would be:

`coalesce`:

```
case
    when value1 is not null then value1
    when value2 is not null then value2
    ... etc
    else null
end
```

`nullif`:

```
case when value1 = value2 then null else value1 end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
T coalesce(T a, T b) {
    if(a != null) return a;
    return b;
}
        
T nullif(T a, T b) {
    if(a == b) return null; 
    return a;
}
```

Comment: The question is asking about the difference between the two. I'm not sure this will be especially useful to someone not already familiar with the difference. Can you [edit] your answer to provide more explanation?